# Problemas com .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, osx, mac

Fala Galera, esto com um problema bem estranho, eu tenho o seguinte htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^galeria/$ galeria.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^contato/$ contato.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Este acima funciona direitinho, porém, se eu adiciono mais uma RewriteRule simples, por exemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^fotos/$ fotos.php [NC,L]
```

Essa nova NÃO FUNCIONA!

Pelas pesquisas que eu fiz, a galera fala pra reiniciar o apache ou fazer um .htaccess novo. Já reiniciei o apache, já excluí o .htaccess e digitei de novo e não resolve.

**OBS.: Mesmo EXCLUINDO o .htaccess e reinciando o apache, as regras para galeria e contato CONTINUAM funcionando.**

Eu estou usando o apache nativo do MacOS, o ATOM como editor e sou novo com URL amigáveis. Qual o erro que estou cometendo?

***É possível o arquivo .htaccess ter ficado salvo em cache???? Porque parece que aconteceu isso, eu edito o arquivo, excluo, causo "erros" dentro dele e nada acontece, mantém as regras que eu havia criado semana passa.
Eu estou perguntando isso porque está acontecendo cache com o arquivo css, Se eu modifico o arquivo css hoje, ele não funciona ao menos que eu vá no navegador é digite na url:***

```
localhost/site/css/estilo.css
```

Comment: Se as regras continuam funcionando quando voce deleta o arquivo, minha aposta é que você está modificando o arquivo errado.

Comment: Então. Eu suspeitei disso mas deixei o projeto salvo no ATOM (coloquei uma observação a mais na pergunta), as alterações feitas nos demais arquivos funcionam.

Comment: Não é o cache? Vc testou em sistemas diferentes?

Comment: @SIdon Eu limpei o cache dos navegadores, engraçado que ele está fazendo isso no Safari, Chrome e Firefox. Esse é o único sistema que está no Mac por enquanto, eu tenho outros no Wamp, numa máquina Windows aqui, e o teste que eu fiz no Wamp é que excluindo o .htaccess, as url amigáveis param.

Comment: Tentou em um browser totalmente 'limpo'? tente no [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/download/) para ver o resultado.

Comment: @Sidon Fiz o download do Vivaldi e aconteceu a mesma coisa. Nesse meio tempo eu também instalei o [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) e lá não funciona nada.

Comment: Tu está usando a tag base?
Se tu mudou o href da base para buscar os arquivos de outro servidor, tudo que tu mudar local não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Outra coisa é se tu não tem uma pasta chamada fotos na tua estrutura de arquivos

Comment: @VítorAndré Estou usando a tag base sim: `<base href="localhost">`, não tenho uma pasta chamada fotos. Está acontecendo como se eu tivesse editando o arquivo errado pois nada acontece. Isso poderia ser cache também mas em 4 navegadores "limpos"?

Comment: @Sidon Acho que resolvi o problema, Usei o MAMP (Wamp para MacOS) e funcionou. Deve ser algum problema de cache do apache2 nativo do OSX... Eu segui esse [tutorial](https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba) para alterar o http.conf ( liberar usuário e alterar documentRoot ). Eu vou fazer mais alguns testes para ter certeza antes de responder a pergunta e marcar como resolvido.